# Error in creating a custom validation using mongoose with typescript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

```
 import mongoose, { Schema, model } from "mongoose";

 var breakfastSchema = new Schema({
      eggs: {
        type: Number,
        min: [6, "Too few eggs"],
        max: 12
      },
      bacon: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, "Why no bacon?"]
      },
      drink: {
        type: String,
        enum: ["Coffee", "Tea"],
        required: function() {
          return this.bacon > 3;
        }
      }
    });
```

The two errors that I get when I run this code are:

- Property 'bacon' does not exist on type '{ type: StringConstructor;
  enum: string[]; required: () => any; }'
- 'required' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to type-check the `required` function, TypeScript needs to know what type of object `this` will refer to when `required` is called.  By default, TypeScript guesses (incorrectly) that `required` will be called as a method of the containing object literal.  Since Mongoose will actually call `required` with `this` set to a document of the structure you're defining, you'll need to define a TypeScript interface for that document type (if you don't already have one) and then specify a `this` parameter to the `required` function.

```
interface Breakfast {
    eggs?: number;
    bacon: number;
    drink?: "Coffee" | "Tea";
}

var breakfastSchema = new Schema({
     eggs: {
       type: Number,
       min: [6, "Too few eggs"],
       max: 12
     },
     bacon: {
       type: Number,
       required: [true, "Why no bacon?"]
     },
     drink: {
       type: String,
       enum: ["Coffee", "Tea"],
       required: function(this: Breakfast) {
         return this.bacon > 3;
       }
     }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Matt McCutchen. I wonder if a problem could be solved by creating a type instead of an interface, because however as the documentation says I have to define a type, and therefore it seems very exaggerated to define the same schema first in the mongoose scheme, then as an interface and finally as a type.`export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
  email: string,
name: string
};



const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
name{ type: String, unique: true },
});`

Comment: Yes, you can probably use that `UserModel` type.  It's a question of whether the `this` object passed to the `required` function has the built-in `mongoose.Document` properties as well as the ones specific to your schema.  I would guess that it does, but you could always test that.

Answer (score 0):

In my `tscongig.json` file inside `compilerOptions`, I changed the following and it worked:

```
"noImplicitThis": false, 
...
/* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
```